# How we get dynamic list in design:component from datasource class?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, design

I want a picklist dynamically create by current recordId in design: component, I am not able to get current recordId in datasource class.[image]

Comment: why you want record id in design:component . you can just implement interface "force:hasrecordId"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I want recordId in datasource class because I want a pick list in design: component which is getting by recordId.If I implement "force:hasrecordId" then i am able to get recordId in the only aura: component and its controller not in datasource class.